# Custom React Router Prompt: A history supports only one prompt at a time

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have created a custom React Router Prompt to show when the user wants to navigate to other page and have not saved the data yet.

Everything seems to be working as it should, but I have an annoying warning:

```
Warning: A history supports only one prompt at a time
```

The component looks like this:

```
export function RouterPrompt(props) {
    const {when, onOK, onCancel, title} = props;

    const history = useHistory();

    const [showPrompt, setShowPrompt] = useState(false);
    const [currentPath, setCurrentPath] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        if (when) {
            history.block((prompt) => {
                setCurrentPath(prompt.pathname);
                setShowPrompt(true);
                return "true";
            });
        } else {
            history.block(() => {
            });
        }
    }, [when]);

    const handleOK = useCallback(async () => {
        if (onOK) {
            const canRoute = await Promise.resolve(onOK());
            if (canRoute) {
                history.block(() => {
                });
                history.push(currentPath);
            }
        }
    }, [currentPath, history, onOK]);

    const handleCancel = useCallback(async () => {
        if (onCancel) {
            const canRoute = await Promise.resolve(onCancel());
            if (canRoute) {
                history.block(() => {
                });
                history.push(currentPath);
            }
        }
        setShowPrompt(false);
    }, [currentPath, history, onCancel]);

    return showPrompt ? (
        <Dialog
            open={showPrompt}
            onClose={handleCancel}
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        >
            <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
                {title}
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
                <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                    There are unsaved changes. Are you sure want to leave this page?
                </DialogContentText>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={handleCancel}>Stay on page</Button>
                <Button onClick={handleOK} autoFocus>
                    Leave
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
    ) : null;
}
```

As far as I was able to do some research on this, this comes from the class lifecycle methods (useEffect runs before unmouting the current history.block), but in reality only one Prompt is rendered in the DOM.

### Edit

I have discovered another bug, that this will change the path regardless of the actual push or not. So in the URL the path changes but the view don't, so next time when you press back and Confirm, instaed of staying on the page, you will be 2 steps back in history.

Comment: Have you tried removing `history` from the `useEffect` dependency array?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that one. It seems to work as before also, and the number of warnings are reduced a little bit (with that I only get one warning), but the warning is still there.

Comment: What about `when`? Does it change often? Could that be re-rendering the whole component?

Comment: Afaik it should re-render when the `when` prop changes. That's when the Prompt will be added to the DOM.
Updated the code to its current version. This works as it should, so the Prompt only appears when the when prop is set and removed when the `when` changes to `false`. 
However it seems for me that any time `history.block` runs, it throws an error.
Is there a command maybe which removes the current block first?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have completely restructured/refactored my code (original code was from a blog post), this seems to be working perfectly (without warnings) and as expected:

```
export function RouterPrompt(props) {
    const {when, title} = props;

    const history = useHistory();

    const [showPrompt, setShowPrompt] = useState(false);
    const [currentPath, setCurrentPath] = useState("");

    const unblockRef = useRef();

    function handleShowModal() {
        setShowPrompt(true);
    }

    function onCancel() {
        setShowPrompt(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        unblockRef.current = history.block((location) => {
            if (when) {
                setCurrentPath(location.pathname);
                handleShowModal();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
        return () => {
            unblockRef.current && unblockRef.current();
        };
    }, [when]);

    function handleConfirm() {
        if (unblockRef) {
            unblockRef.current();
        }
        setShowPrompt(false);
        history.push(currentPath);
    }

    return (
        <Dialog
            open={showPrompt}
            onClose={onCancel}
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        >
            <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
                {title}
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
                <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                    There are unsaved changes. Are you sure want to leave this page?
                </DialogContentText>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={onCancel}>Stay on page</Button>
                <Button onClick={handleConfirm} autoFocus>
                    Leave
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
    );
}
```

Comment: Kristof, what was the cause of that message?

Comment: I'm not really sure what was the original cause, but it was something regarding the useEffect return() hook. It seemed it is not removing or removing the handler too early

Comment: then why did you add the useRef ?

Comment: That is needed to clean up the history handler correctly. Otherwise you would get the error above "A history supports only one prompt at a time". But you can try it with the original code in the original post.

Comment: Thanks! The return function inside the useEffect fixed the warning :)